# ServiceReferences.ClientConfig relative addresses and https

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I use relative addresses in ServiceReferences.ClientConfig for silverlight.  Everything works great.  Then I switched to https.

I then realized that I no longer see this with the relative:

../myservice.svc

instead of

https://mysite/myservice.svc

Can you do relative addresses with https?

It is the endpoint address that is relative.

```
   <endpoint address="../WCFProxies/WCF.svc"
                      binding="customBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="IWCF"
                      contract="IWCF"
                      name="CustomBinding_WCF" />
```

Comment: Relative is not specific to http or https; can you post your config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do relative HTTPS of course. The problem is that HTTPS & HTTP are not interchangeable. that is, http://www.domain.com/page can't access https://www.domain.com/otherpage in a relative way. for this matter they are two different domains altogether. What you might want to do is to maybe server your XAP from HTTPS as well. that way the relative url would work.